# Why won't some pictures show up in certain browsers but other photos of similar size and file do?

Tags: html

I built a website, http://charlottemobiletrainers.com and the main logo on the index page shows up for me using Chrome but not in Safari and doesn't show up for my friend on their laptop in any browser. The photo was a ".gif" and I changed the file to ".png" just to see if that changed anything but it didn't help. And then I tried renaming the file because I used "_" in it originally but that didn't help. I don't know what else to try.

The image is currently in my style.css file. Could that be the problem?

Comment: It's HTML.  That's the way it's designed.

Comment: What do you mean by "The image is currently in my style.css file?"

Answer (score 0):

You've laid it out quite oddly to start with. I would do it like this:

```
<div id="featured">
  <div class="left">
<h3>Mobile Personal Trainers</h3>
<p>Are you ready for summertime in Charlotte? Let Mobile Trainers help you look and  feel your best with a personalized workout program <i>JUST FOR YOU!</i> Our personal trainers will go wherever you want whenever you want. Let's get started!</p>
     <input type="button" value="Get Started!" onclick="parent.location='contact.html'">
 </div>
 <div class="right">
     <img src="logo.png" width="blah" height="blah" alt=""/>
 </div>
```

Then set the #feature to the width and height you want it to be then set the class .right to whatever width the logo is and the remaining width set to the .left class.

Comment: Also why are you using html5 when you don't have any html5 tags :P

Comment: And you can remove all your padding apart from padding-bottom in feature